# spring tool suite can not deploy example webservice on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment, suite

I have some experience with EJB and JBoss and know the basics about Webservices, but I'm new to Spring.

So I tried to deploy the example Spring WS project gs-rest-service-complete without any changes. It is running on Spring Boot, but I cannot deploy and access it on an external Tomcat Server.

This is what I did: I installed Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE and 
Apache Tomcat 8.0.24 and defined Tomcat as a new Server in Spring Tool Suite.
It seems to work because I can deploy (and access) the example Spring MVC project and I can deploy another (not Spring Example) Webservice on Tomcat.

However I cannot deploy the gs-rest-service-complete project. I changed packaging in pom.xml to 'war', but it didn't help. Any hints what I could do?

Thanks, caduta

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer at the bottom of this site:
https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

I had to do three steps to get it running:

- change packaging to war in pom.xml.
- comment out the declaration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom.xml.
- change the Application class to inherit from SpringBootServletInitializer and override method configure. This is necessary to register the application in tomcat.

Now the Application class looks like this:

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration; 
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder; 
    import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }
    }
```